# change the position of animated string in java script

Tags: javascript, animation

here is the code from Code Academy :http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-girf5/0/1 to get an animated name. the animated string is somewhere close to the top. is there any way that it can be re-positioned such that the animation will be right at the center of the screen?here is the code:
      main.js:

```
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = "Codecademy";
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

if(10 < 3) {
    bubbleShape = "square";
}
else {
    bubbleShape = "circle";
}

drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceBubbles();
```

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = "Codecademy";
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

if(10 < 3) {
    bubbleShape = "square";
}
else {
    bubbleShape = "circle";
}

drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceBubbles();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running through the bubbles.js script  that codecademy has linked to:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js

And then copying them locally for your site, and altering them as needed...

Look at/edit this section (within the drawName, or the "output" function):

```
for (var j=0; j<g.length; j++) {
    g[j].curPos.x = (canvasWidth/2 - offset/2) + g[j].curPos.x;
    g[j].curPos.y = (canvasHeight/2 - 180) + g[j].curPos.y;
    g[j].originalPos.x = (canvasWidth/2 - offset/2) + g[j].originalPos.x;
    g[j].originalPos.y = (canvasHeight/2 - 180) + g[j].originalPos.y;
}
```

I would suggest try altering the formula in this line `(canvasHeight/2 - 180)` to change the output position... I'm just guessing, but that is what jumps out at me in this code.

Comment: i got the files in my system Phlume, am new to this and am not sure what to edit to change the postition of the output.

Comment: how can i change that code to get the animation right at the center?

Comment: That is a tough question to answer...it is relative. The "center" is dependent on the size of the canvas and the amount of letters in your string. Fiddle with it... substitute 90 for the 180...see what happens. Replace the 180 with a 50; what happens? Replace it with 250...view the results. The point is to **explore** and discover, not just "ask" for the answer. that isn't what this site is about.

Comment: thanks for your answers Phlume :) am already giving that a try